# See numerical count of how many datasets are in my bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm aware of the API list endpoint but want to know if there is a way to see how many datasets I have on my project. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [`BigQuery Mate`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) Chrome Extension and enjoy.
You will see how many datasets in your project and how many tables in each dataset as well as many other perks

Comment: that was fast! did you have it installed already or just installed  - just curious :o)

Comment: Will accept the answer once available, thanks again!

Comment: sure, please do when have chance